# Java- Simple Neural Network Implementation not working

Tags: java, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a neural network with:

1. 5 input nodes(+1 bias)
2. 1 hidden layer of 1 hidden node(+1 bias)
3. 1 output unit.

The training data I'm using is the a disjunction of 5 input units. The Overall Error is oscillating instead of decreasing and reaching very high numbers.

```
package neuralnetworks;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NeuralNetworks {
    private double[] weightslayer1;
    private double[] weightslayer2;
    private int[][] training;


    public NeuralNetworks(int inputLayerSize, int weights1, int weights2) {
        weightslayer1 = new double[weights1];
        weightslayer2 = new double[weights2];

    }

    public static int[][] readCSV() {
        Scanner readfile = null;
        try {
            readfile = new Scanner(new File("disjunction.csv"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scanner delimit;
        int[][] train = new int[32][6];
        int lines = 0;
        while (readfile.hasNext()) {
            String line = readfile.nextLine();
            delimit = new Scanner(line);
            delimit.useDelimiter(",");
            int features = 0;
            while (delimit.hasNext() && lines > 0) {
                train[lines - 1][features] = Integer.parseInt(delimit.next());
                features++;
            }

            lines++;
        }
        return train;

    }

    public double linearcomb(double[] input, double[] weights) { //calculates the sum of the multiplication of weights and inputs
        double sigma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            sigma += (input[i] * weights[i]);

        }
        return sigma;
    }

    public double hiddenLayerOutput(int[] inputs) { //calculates the output of the hiddenlayer

        double[] formattedInput = new double[6]; //adds the bias unit
        formattedInput[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < formattedInput.length; i++)
            formattedInput[i] = inputs[i - 1];
        double hlOutput = linearcomb(formattedInput, weightslayer1);
        return hlOutput;

    }

    public double feedForward(int[] inputs) { //calculates the output

        double hlOutput = hiddenLayerOutput(inputs);
        double[] olInput = new double[2];
        olInput[0] = 1;
        olInput[1] = hlOutput;

        double output = linearcomb(olInput, weightslayer2);
        return output;
    }

    public void backprop(double predoutput, double targetout, double hidout, double learningrate, int[] input) {

        double outputdelta = predoutput * (1 - predoutput) * (targetout - predoutput);
        double hiddendelta = hidout * (1 - hidout) * (outputdelta * weightslayer2[1]);

        updateweights(learningrate, outputdelta, hiddendelta, input);

    }

    public void updateweights(double learningrate, double outputdelta, double hiddendelta, int[] input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < weightslayer1.length; i++) {
            double deltaw1 = learningrate * hiddendelta * input[i];
            weightslayer1[i] += deltaw1;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < weightslayer2.length; i++) {
            double deltaw2 = learningrate * outputdelta * hiddenLayerOutput(input);
            weightslayer2[i] += deltaw2;
        }

    }

    public double test(int[] inputs) {

        return feedForward(inputs);
    }

    public void train() {
        double learningrate = 0.01;
        double output;
        double hiddenoutput;

        double error = 100;
        do {
            error = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < training.length; i++) {
                output = feedForward(training[i]);
                error += (training[i][5] - output) * (training[i][5] - output) / 2;
                hiddenoutput = hiddenLayerOutput(training[i]);

                backprop(output, training[i][5], hiddenoutput, learningrate, training[i]);
            }
            //System.out.println(error);

        }while(error>1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NeuralNetworks nn = new NeuralNetworks(6, 6, 2);
        Random rand = new Random();

        nn.weightslayer2[0] = (rand.nextDouble() - 0.5);
        nn.weightslayer2[1] = (rand.nextDouble() - 0.5);

        for (int i = 0; i < nn.weightslayer1.length; i++)
            nn.weightslayer1[i] = (rand.nextDouble() - 0.5);

        nn.training = readCSV();
        /*for (int i = 0; i < nn.training.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nn.training[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(nn.training[i][j] + ",");
            System.out.println();

        }*/
        nn.train();

        int[] testa = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        System.out.println(nn.test(testa));

    }
}
```

Comment: There may be several causes. My first guess: you don't seem to use any non-linearity (sigmoid, rectified linear, ...) in your hidden layer. Are you trying to do regression, not classification, right?

Comment: The neural network should be able to or 5 inputs, I thought using linear regression would work that is why I didn't add non-linearity. Is that correct?

Comment: So you want to do regression. That is, your output is a real number, not a discrete value. This means that you don't need the non-linear logistic function in the *output layer*. Anyway, you need some non-linearity in your **hidden layer**.

Comment: If he is just trying to do a logical or, shouldn't a linear function be fine?

Comment: I think the real problem is that he only has one possible output that produces a 0. This heavily biases the network towards 1, and makes it more vulnerable to random chance in the input.